# Bug in UWP StreamSocket, ReadAsync hangs

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp

I believe I found a serious bug in StreamSocket implementation. I googled on this and found no info if this is a known issue.

The problem is that if the read buffer is small and read operation internally has read more bytes than it filled in the provided buffer, the next read operation will hang instead of returning data from the internal buffer in case if the buffer for second operation is larger than the size of the remaining chunk in StreamSocket's internal buffer.

UWP version:

```
StreamSocket sock = new StreamSocket();
byte[] b1 = new byte[4]; // Small buffer for 1st read.
byte[] b2 = new byte[1024]; // Large buffer for 2nd read.
await sock.ConnectAsync(new HostName("smtp.gmail.com"), "25");
Stream inputStream = sock.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
int n1 = await inputStream.ReadAsync(b1, 0, b1.Length);
int n2 = await inputStream.ReadAsync(b2, 0, b2.Length); // Hangs here.
sock.Dispose();
```

.NET Core version:

```
Socket sock = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
await sock.ConnectAsync("smtp.gmail.com", 25);
NetworkStream inputStream = new NetworkStream(sock);
byte[] b1 = new byte[4]; // Small buffer for 1st read.
byte[] b2 = new byte[1024]; // Large buffer for 2nd read.
int n1 = await inputStream.ReadAsync(b1, 0, b1.Length);
int n2 = await inputStream.ReadAsync(b2, 0, b2.Length); // Works like a charm.
inputStream.Dispose();
sock.Dispose();
```

Also, StreamSocket does not provide (or I was unable to find it) any way to determine the count of bytes remaining in its internal buffer. I see this value in the debugger but it's not public. If this info were available, I'd be able to at least request the exact number of bytes still available in the internal buffer (in this case ReadAsync works) and thus work this issue around. Of course, I could utilize Reflection for that but I don't want to rely on peeking private variables of StreamSocket and Stream classes.

Tested with Universal Windows SDK Version 10.0.14393.0

Is it the intended behavior or indeed a bug there?

EDIT:

Well, I was able to make this working with UWP using IInputStream:

```
StreamSocket sock = new StreamSocket();
await sock.ConnectAsync(new HostName("smtp.gmail.com"), "25");
Stream inputStream = sock.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer buf1 = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(4);
IBuffer outBuf1 = await sock.InputStream.ReadAsync(buf1, 4, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer buf2 = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(1024);
IBuffer outBuf2 = await sock.InputStream.ReadAsync(buf2, 1024, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
sock.Dispose();
```

However, I cannot use this in production code which (for other reasons) has to use Stream, not IInputStream. And I believe it must anyway work correctly with Stream if this functionality is exposed (and it is).

Comment: I think  _bug_ is in the .NET core not in UWP. In my opinion UWP works like it should be. If you specified how many bytes you want to read this method should return the requested amount.

Comment: So, how many bytes _are_ in the internal buffer at the second `ReadAsync()`? Can you see what code it's blocking on internally?

Comment: @m.rogalski No, the buffer size only specifies the max count of bytes to receive. The returned value of ReadAsync specifies how many bytes have actually been read (it can be less or the same as the input buffer size).

Comment: @CodeCaster In debugger, I see that Stream has _readPos=4 and _readLen=53. So, I guess 53 is the count of bytes in the internal buffer. That's all the info I can get from the debugger.

Comment: @Alex For me the bug is when I expect _let's say_ 64 bytes and received only 48 with the rest being `\0`.

Comment: @m.rogalski I think you're confusing the OP. `ReadAsync()` can return less bytes than requested, that's valid socket behavior. You cannot "expect" a streaming socket to read a set amount of bytes. If you do, and it doesn't, then that's a violation of your application protocol, but that's not relevant here.

Comment: @m.rogalski You can't tell ReadAsync how many bytes you want to receive, sockets don't work this way. You just can tell it "I can receive up to the specified number of bytes".

Comment: @Alex: That would be a bug, and it would be a very serious bug. If you're absolutely sure the stream has buffered more bytes during the first read, I'd go ahead and report it.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes, I see in the debugger that the stream internally read more bytes (53 bytes) than the initial buffer length (4 bytes).

Comment: Well it's no problem that the internal buffer contains more bytes than the buffer you provided. The internal buffer is probably filled with the entire SMTP "220 service ready" message which was received in one TCP packet.

Comment: @CodeCaster And it's expected that the next ReadAsync call will return the contents of this internal buffer (and this is what happens with non-UWP case and NetworkStream). But if does not do the same in UWP case. Instead, it just hangs.

Comment: Yeah I know, I mean you shouldn't focus on the internal buffer I guess. But as far as I know, the UWP source has not been published. Have a go at it using a decompiler if you want to figure this out. I cannot try to reproduce this at the moment.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think internal buffer is important because if I read everything within a single operation (i.e. if original buffer I supply to the ReadAsync is more than 53 bytes), it completes just fine. ReadAsync works when the internal buffer is empty. And I see this in the debugger as well. The problem only happens if something still remains in the internal buffer from the previous operation. Now it's up to MS to decide if they should do anything with that or not.

Comment: As far as I know, every higher-level library (SMTP, HTTP, FTP, ...) uses this socket, so if there were a problem where the first read wouldn't starve the internal buffer, a _lot_ of applications would hang. Or there are just not that many applications using small buffers, but I beg to differ. Like I said, I can't reproduce this at the moment, there may be something else at play. For all we know you have a crappy network filter driver or whatever, and the bug is not in UWP nor .NET.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133091/discussion-between-alex-and-codecaster).